# Linux g++ new (std::nothrow) does work

Tags: c++, nothrow

I am using c++ constant value std::nothrow in new operator to avoid exception on failure, and return a null instead.
But as I tried, this seems not work on my environment is g++ 4.4.4 on Linux x86_64.

Following is the testing program and execution result:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <new>
#include <iostream>

class TT {
public:
    TT(int size);
    ~TT();
private:
    char * buffer;
};

TT::TT(int size) : buffer(NULL) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    buffer = (char *)malloc(size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
}

TT::~TT() {
    if (buffer != NULL) {
        delete buffer;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    TT * tt = NULL;
    try {
        tt = new  TT(0);
    } catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) {
        std::cout << "tt exception caught" << std::endl;
    }

    tt = new (std::nothrow) TT(0);
    if (tt == NULL) {
        std::cout << "tt is null" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "tt is not null" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execute result:

```
$ uname -i
x86_64
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ t.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
tt exception caught
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

From the output message, there is an exception thrown; but I wish it should not, instead a null pointer return is expected.
Can anybody help me with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: You are throwing the exception in the TT constructor : if (size <= 0) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

Comment: Thanks, @JuniorDussouillez

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course there's a `std::bad_alloc` thrown. **Your own code throws it**.

`new (std::nothrow)` only specifies that the memory allocator of the new expression won't throw. But once your `TT` object is being constructed in that memory, it may still throw any exception it likes.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is very clear;
so the std::nothrow only take effect on memory allocation stage; after memory is allocated, the explicited exception thrown by the user-define constructor function will not be silent.

Comment: @Hui - Yup, it's the only sane thing the language can do.